# function override issue wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image-upload

I have image upload function in my WordPress `function.php` file but my `function.php` file is encoded with an ioncube encoder so I can't edit that function.

but I have a complete code of that function given by my theme author. and author told me to override that function it will work.

my function name is `pinc_upload_pin()` and it is added like `add_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin');`

now I need to override that above function.

i have tried like create one separate file name function_new.php and include it in `header.php` like using `require_once`. i have remove above function using `remove_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin');`

and add my own function and hook it. below is my `function_new.php` code

```
remove_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin');

function pinc_upload_pin_new(){ 
    check_ajax_referer('upload_pin', 'ajax-nonce');

    do_action('pinc_before_upload_pin', $_POST);

    $minWidth = 2;
    $minHeight = 2;

    $minWidth = apply_filters('pinc_minwidth', $minWidth);
    $minHeight = apply_filters('pinc_minheight', $minHeight);

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');

    if ($_POST['mode'] == 'computer') {
        if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {          
                $imageTypes = array (
                    1, //IMAGETYPE_GIF
                    2, //IMAGETYPE_JPEG
                    3 //IMAGETYPE_PNG
                );

                $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                $width = @$imageinfo[0];
                $height = @$imageinfo[1];
                $type = @$imageinfo[2];
                $mime = @$imageinfo['mime'];

                if (!in_array($type, $imageTypes)) {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'error';
                    die();
                }

                if ($width < $minWidth || $height < $minWidth) {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'errorsize';
                    die();
                }

                if($mime != 'image/gif' && $mime != 'image/jpeg' && $mime != 'image/png') {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'error';
                    die();
                }

                switch($type) {
                    case 1:
                        $ext = '.gif';

                        //check if is animated gif
                        $frames = 0;
                        if(($fh = @fopen($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'], 'rb')) && $error != 'error') {
                            while(!feof($fh) && $frames < 2) {
                                $chunk = fread($fh, 1024 * 100); //read 100kb at a time
                                $frames += preg_match_all('#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00(\x2C|\x21)#s', $chunk, $matches);
                           }
                        }
                        fclose($fh);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $ext = '.jpg';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $ext = '.png';
                        break;
                }
                $transliterationTable = array('á' => 'a', 'Á' => 'A', 'à' => 'a', 'À' => 'A', 'ă' => 'a', 'Ă' => 'A', 'â' => 'a', 'Â' => 'A', 'å' => 'a', 'Å' => 'A', 'ã' => 'a', 'Ã' => 'A', 'ą' => 'a', 'Ą' => 'A', 'ā' => 'a', 'Ā' => 'A', 'ä' => 'ae', 'Ä' => 'AE', 'æ' => 'ae', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'ḃ' => 'b', 'Ḃ' => 'B', 'ć' => 'c', 'Ć' => 'C', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'č' => 'c', 'Č' => 'C', 'ċ' => 'c', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'ç' => 'c', 'Ç' => 'C', 'ď' => 'd', 'Ď' => 'D', 'ḋ' => 'd', 'Ḋ' => 'D', 'đ' => 'd', 'Đ' => 'D', 'ð' => 'dh', 'Ð' => 'Dh', 'é' => 'e', 'É' => 'E', 'è' => 'e', 'È' => 'E', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'ê' => 'e', 'Ê' => 'E', 'ě' => 'e', 'Ě' => 'E', 'ë' => 'e', 'Ë' => 'E', 'ė' => 'e', 'Ė' => 'E', 'ę' => 'e', 'Ę' => 'E', 'ē' => 'e', 'Ē' => 'E', 'ḟ' => 'f', 'Ḟ' => 'F', 'ƒ' => 'f', 'Ƒ' => 'F', 'ğ' => 'g', 'Ğ' => 'G', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'ġ' => 'g', 'Ġ' => 'G', 'ģ' => 'g', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'ĥ' => 'h', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'ħ' => 'h', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'í' => 'i', 'Í' => 'I', 'ì' => 'i', 'Ì' => 'I', 'î' => 'i', 'Î' => 'I', 'ï' => 'i', 'Ï' => 'I', 'ĩ' => 'i', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'į' => 'i', 'Į' => 'I', 'ī' => 'i', 'Ī' => 'I', 'ĵ' => 'j', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'ķ' => 'k', 'Ķ' => 'K', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'Ĺ' => 'L', 'ľ' => 'l', 'Ľ' => 'L', 'ļ' => 'l', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'ł' => 'l', 'Ł' => 'L', 'ṁ' => 'm', 'Ṁ' => 'M', 'ń' => 'n', 'Ń' => 'N', 'ň' => 'n', 'Ň' => 'N', 'ñ' => 'n', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'ņ' => 'n', 'Ņ' => 'N', 'ó' => 'o', 'Ó' => 'O', 'ò' => 'o', 'Ò' => 'O', 'ô' => 'o', 'Ô' => 'O', 'ő' => 'o', 'Ő' => 'O', 'õ' => 'o', 'Õ' => 'O', 'ø' => 'oe', 'Ø' => 'OE', 'ō' => 'o', 'Ō' => 'O', 'ơ' => 'o', 'Ơ' => 'O', 'ö' => 'oe', 'Ö' => 'OE', 'ṗ' => 'p', 'Ṗ' => 'P', 'ŕ' => 'r', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'ř' => 'r', 'Ř' => 'R', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'ś' => 's', 'Ś' => 'S', 'ŝ' => 's', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'š' => 's', 'Š' => 'S', 'ṡ' => 's', 'Ṡ' => 'S', 'ş' => 's', 'Ş' => 'S', 'ș' => 's', 'Ș' => 'S', 'ß' => 'SS', 'ť' => 't', 'Ť' => 'T', 'ṫ' => 't', 'Ṫ' => 'T', 'ţ' => 't', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'ț' => 't', 'Ț' => 'T', 'ŧ' => 't', 'Ŧ' => 'T', 'ú' => 'u', 'Ú' => 'U', 'ù' => 'u', 'Ù' => 'U', 'ŭ' => 'u', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'û' => 'u', 'Û' => 'U', 'ů' => 'u', 'Ů' => 'U', 'ű' => 'u', 'Ű' => 'U', 'ũ' => 'u', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'ų' => 'u', 'Ų' => 'U', 'ū' => 'u', 'Ū' => 'U', 'ư' => 'u', 'Ư' => 'U', 'ü' => 'ue', 'Ü' => 'UE', 'ẃ' => 'w', 'Ẃ' => 'W', 'ẁ' => 'w', 'Ẁ' => 'W', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'Ŵ' => 'W', 'ẅ' => 'w', 'Ẅ' => 'W', 'ý' => 'y', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'ỳ' => 'y', 'Ỳ' => 'Y', 'ŷ' => 'y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'ÿ' => 'y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'ź' => 'z', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'ž' => 'z', 'Ž' => 'Z', 'ż' => 'z', 'Ż' => 'Z', 'þ' => 'th', 'Þ' => 'Th', 'µ' => 'u', 'а' => 'a', 'А' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'Б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'В' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'Г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'Д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'Е' => 'E', 'ё' => 'e', 'Ё' => 'E', 'ж' => 'zh', 'Ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'З' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'И' => 'i', 'й' => 'j', 'Й' => 'j', 'к' => 'k', 'К' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'Л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'М' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'Н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'О' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'П' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'Р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'С' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'Т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'У' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'Ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'Х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'Ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch', 'Ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'Ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'Щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'Ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'Ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'Ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'Э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'ju', 'Ю' => 'ju', 'я' => 'ja', 'Я' => 'ja');

                $fname = $_FILES[$file]['name'];
                $fname = str_replace(array_keys($transliterationTable), array_values($transliterationTable), $fname);
                $filename = time() . str_shuffle('pcl48');
                $original_filename = preg_replace('/[^(\x20|\x61-\x7A)]*/', '', strtolower(str_ireplace($ext, '', $fname))); //preg_replace('/[^(\x48-\x7A)]*/' strips non-utf character. Ref: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000
                $_FILES[$file]['name'] = strtolower(substr($original_filename, 0, 100)) . '-' . $filename . $ext;

                $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);

                if (is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'error';
                    die();
                } else {
                    if ($frames > 1) {
                        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'a_gif', 'yes');
                    }
                }
            }   
        }

        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'pinc_unattached', 'yes');

        $return = array();

        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id, 'medium');
        $return['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail[0];
        $return['id'] = $attach_id;

        do_action('pinc_after_upload_pin_computer', $attach_id);
        echo json_encode($return);
    } else if ($_POST['mode'] == 'web') {
        $url = esc_url_raw($_POST['pin_upload_web']);

        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            $image = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        } elseif (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
            $image = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        }

        if (!$image) {
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        $filename = time() . str_shuffle('pcl48');
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/" . $filename . '.tmp';
        $filetmp = file_put_contents($file_array['tmp_name'], $image);

        if (!$filetmp) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        $imageTypes = array (
            1, //IMAGETYPE_GIF
            2, //IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            3 //IMAGETYPE_PNG
        );

        $imageinfo = getimagesize($file_array['tmp_name']);
        $width = @$imageinfo[0];
        $height = @$imageinfo[1];
        $type = @$imageinfo[2];
        $mime = @$imageinfo['mime'];

        if (!in_array ($type, $imageTypes)) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        if ($width < $minWidth || $height < $minWidth) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'errorsize';
            die();
        }

        if($mime != 'image/gif' && $mime != 'image/jpeg' && $mime != 'image/png') {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        switch($type) {
            case 1:
                $ext = '.gif';

                //check if is animated gif
                $frame = 0;
                if(($fh = @fopen($file_array['tmp_name'], 'rb')) && $error != 'error') {
                    while(!feof($fh) && $frames < 2) {
                        $chunk = fread($fh, 1024 * 100); //read 100kb at a time
                        $frames += preg_match_all('#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00(\x2C|\x21)#s', $chunk, $matches);
                   }
                }
                fclose($fh);

                break;
            case 2:
                $ext = '.jpg';
                break;
            case 3:
                $ext = '.png';
                break;
        }
        $original_filename = preg_replace('/[^(\x20|\x61-\x7A)]*/', '', strtolower(str_ireplace($ext, '', basename($url)))); //preg_replace('/[^(\x48-\x7A)]*/' strips non-utf character. Ref: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000
        $file_array['name'] = strtolower(substr($original_filename, 0, 100)) . '-' . $filename . $ext;

        $attach_id = media_handle_sideload($file_array, $post_id);

        if (is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        } else {
            if ($frames > 1) {
                update_post_meta($attach_id, 'a_gif', 'yes');
            }
        }

        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'pinc_unattached', 'yes');

        $return = array();
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id, 'medium');
        $return['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail[0];
        $return['id'] = $attach_id;

        do_action('pinc_after_upload_pin_web', $attach_id);
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin_new');
```

but my this new function could not call. it still call old function `pinc_upload_pin();`

please guide me where i am missing something

Comment: Are you sure that the `pinc_upload_pin` hook already have been added when you try to remove it, so your code isn't run before they add that hook?

Comment: pinc_upload_pin hook adding in function.php and i am removing that hook in header.php  am i correct ?

Comment: my footer and function both files are encoded so

Comment: is there any possibility that we can override function ?

Comment: I think the issue is that the code you're trying to override is used when a file is getting uploaded. During that request, everything happens without invoking any template/output to the screen (the header.php is never included in that request, which is why your `remove_action()` never gets triggered).

Comment: I know that this isn't much of help, but this is one of the reasons you _never_ should use bought themes that obfuscate the code. Specially if you want to customize them. They are more or less "what you see is what you get" and non-customizable...

Comment: Try add_action( 'init', 'remove_action' ); then call remove_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin'); inside function. in your new function file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok so can you please suggest me solution for that

Comment: i think i have tried your above solution but still function calling

Comment: is there any other possibility using plugin i can modify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you hook you new function with higher priority than your old function and then remove the previous hook inside that function so that only your new function is called.

Not tested but it might work by giving your hook the priority 9( any digit less than 10 because default priority level is 10 if not specified) as below:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin_new',9); // High priority
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin_new',9); // Use this line only if you need this hook for non-logged in users as well

function pinc_upload_pin_new(){
    remove_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin');

    check_ajax_referer('upload_pin', 'ajax-nonce');

    do_action('pinc_before_upload_pin', $_POST);

    $minWidth = 2;
    $minHeight = 2;

    $minWidth = apply_filters('pinc_minwidth', $minWidth);
    $minHeight = apply_filters('pinc_minheight', $minHeight);

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');

    if ($_POST['mode'] == 'computer') {
        if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {          
                $imageTypes = array (
                    1, //IMAGETYPE_GIF
                    2, //IMAGETYPE_JPEG
                    3 //IMAGETYPE_PNG
                );

                $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                $width = @$imageinfo[0];
                $height = @$imageinfo[1];
                $type = @$imageinfo[2];
                $mime = @$imageinfo['mime'];

                if (!in_array($type, $imageTypes)) {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'error';
                    die();
                }

                if ($width < $minWidth || $height < $minWidth) {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'errorsize';
                    die();
                }

                if($mime != 'image/gif' && $mime != 'image/jpeg' && $mime != 'image/png') {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'error';
                    die();
                }

                switch($type) {
                    case 1:
                        $ext = '.gif';

                        //check if is animated gif
                        $frames = 0;
                        if(($fh = @fopen($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'], 'rb')) && $error != 'error') {
                            while(!feof($fh) && $frames < 2) {
                                $chunk = fread($fh, 1024 * 100); //read 100kb at a time
                                $frames += preg_match_all('#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00(\x2C|\x21)#s', $chunk, $matches);
                           }
                        }
                        fclose($fh);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $ext = '.jpg';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $ext = '.png';
                        break;
                }
                $transliterationTable = array('á' => 'a', 'Á' => 'A', 'à' => 'a', 'À' => 'A', 'ă' => 'a', 'Ă' => 'A', 'â' => 'a', 'Â' => 'A', 'å' => 'a', 'Å' => 'A', 'ã' => 'a', 'Ã' => 'A', 'ą' => 'a', 'Ą' => 'A', 'ā' => 'a', 'Ā' => 'A', 'ä' => 'ae', 'Ä' => 'AE', 'æ' => 'ae', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'ḃ' => 'b', 'Ḃ' => 'B', 'ć' => 'c', 'Ć' => 'C', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'č' => 'c', 'Č' => 'C', 'ċ' => 'c', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'ç' => 'c', 'Ç' => 'C', 'ď' => 'd', 'Ď' => 'D', 'ḋ' => 'd', 'Ḋ' => 'D', 'đ' => 'd', 'Đ' => 'D', 'ð' => 'dh', 'Ð' => 'Dh', 'é' => 'e', 'É' => 'E', 'è' => 'e', 'È' => 'E', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'ê' => 'e', 'Ê' => 'E', 'ě' => 'e', 'Ě' => 'E', 'ë' => 'e', 'Ë' => 'E', 'ė' => 'e', 'Ė' => 'E', 'ę' => 'e', 'Ę' => 'E', 'ē' => 'e', 'Ē' => 'E', 'ḟ' => 'f', 'Ḟ' => 'F', 'ƒ' => 'f', 'Ƒ' => 'F', 'ğ' => 'g', 'Ğ' => 'G', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'ġ' => 'g', 'Ġ' => 'G', 'ģ' => 'g', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'ĥ' => 'h', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'ħ' => 'h', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'í' => 'i', 'Í' => 'I', 'ì' => 'i', 'Ì' => 'I', 'î' => 'i', 'Î' => 'I', 'ï' => 'i', 'Ï' => 'I', 'ĩ' => 'i', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'į' => 'i', 'Į' => 'I', 'ī' => 'i', 'Ī' => 'I', 'ĵ' => 'j', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'ķ' => 'k', 'Ķ' => 'K', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'Ĺ' => 'L', 'ľ' => 'l', 'Ľ' => 'L', 'ļ' => 'l', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'ł' => 'l', 'Ł' => 'L', 'ṁ' => 'm', 'Ṁ' => 'M', 'ń' => 'n', 'Ń' => 'N', 'ň' => 'n', 'Ň' => 'N', 'ñ' => 'n', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'ņ' => 'n', 'Ņ' => 'N', 'ó' => 'o', 'Ó' => 'O', 'ò' => 'o', 'Ò' => 'O', 'ô' => 'o', 'Ô' => 'O', 'ő' => 'o', 'Ő' => 'O', 'õ' => 'o', 'Õ' => 'O', 'ø' => 'oe', 'Ø' => 'OE', 'ō' => 'o', 'Ō' => 'O', 'ơ' => 'o', 'Ơ' => 'O', 'ö' => 'oe', 'Ö' => 'OE', 'ṗ' => 'p', 'Ṗ' => 'P', 'ŕ' => 'r', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'ř' => 'r', 'Ř' => 'R', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'ś' => 's', 'Ś' => 'S', 'ŝ' => 's', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'š' => 's', 'Š' => 'S', 'ṡ' => 's', 'Ṡ' => 'S', 'ş' => 's', 'Ş' => 'S', 'ș' => 's', 'Ș' => 'S', 'ß' => 'SS', 'ť' => 't', 'Ť' => 'T', 'ṫ' => 't', 'Ṫ' => 'T', 'ţ' => 't', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'ț' => 't', 'Ț' => 'T', 'ŧ' => 't', 'Ŧ' => 'T', 'ú' => 'u', 'Ú' => 'U', 'ù' => 'u', 'Ù' => 'U', 'ŭ' => 'u', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'û' => 'u', 'Û' => 'U', 'ů' => 'u', 'Ů' => 'U', 'ű' => 'u', 'Ű' => 'U', 'ũ' => 'u', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'ų' => 'u', 'Ų' => 'U', 'ū' => 'u', 'Ū' => 'U', 'ư' => 'u', 'Ư' => 'U', 'ü' => 'ue', 'Ü' => 'UE', 'ẃ' => 'w', 'Ẃ' => 'W', 'ẁ' => 'w', 'Ẁ' => 'W', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'Ŵ' => 'W', 'ẅ' => 'w', 'Ẅ' => 'W', 'ý' => 'y', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'ỳ' => 'y', 'Ỳ' => 'Y', 'ŷ' => 'y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'ÿ' => 'y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'ź' => 'z', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'ž' => 'z', 'Ž' => 'Z', 'ż' => 'z', 'Ż' => 'Z', 'þ' => 'th', 'Þ' => 'Th', 'µ' => 'u', 'а' => 'a', 'А' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'Б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'В' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'Г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'Д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'Е' => 'E', 'ё' => 'e', 'Ё' => 'E', 'ж' => 'zh', 'Ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'З' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'И' => 'i', 'й' => 'j', 'Й' => 'j', 'к' => 'k', 'К' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'Л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'М' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'Н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'О' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'П' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'Р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'С' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'Т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'У' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'Ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'Х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'Ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch', 'Ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'Ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'Щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'Ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'Ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'Ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'Э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'ju', 'Ю' => 'ju', 'я' => 'ja', 'Я' => 'ja');

                $fname = $_FILES[$file]['name'];
                $fname = str_replace(array_keys($transliterationTable), array_values($transliterationTable), $fname);
                $filename = time() . str_shuffle('pcl48');
                $original_filename = preg_replace('/[^(\x20|\x61-\x7A)]*/', '', strtolower(str_ireplace($ext, '', $fname))); //preg_replace('/[^(\x48-\x7A)]*/' strips non-utf character. Ref: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000
                $_FILES[$file]['name'] = strtolower(substr($original_filename, 0, 100)) . '-' . $filename . $ext;

                $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);

                if (is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
                    @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                    echo 'error';
                    die();
                } else {
                    if ($frames > 1) {
                        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'a_gif', 'yes');
                    }
                }
            }   
        }

        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'pinc_unattached', 'yes');

        $return = array();

        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id, 'medium');
        $return['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail[0];
        $return['id'] = $attach_id;

        do_action('pinc_after_upload_pin_computer', $attach_id);
        echo json_encode($return);
    } else if ($_POST['mode'] == 'web') {
        $url = esc_url_raw($_POST['pin_upload_web']);

        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            $image = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        } elseif (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
            $image = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        }

        if (!$image) {
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        $filename = time() . str_shuffle('pcl48');
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/" . $filename . '.tmp';
        $filetmp = file_put_contents($file_array['tmp_name'], $image);

        if (!$filetmp) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        $imageTypes = array (
            1, //IMAGETYPE_GIF
            2, //IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            3 //IMAGETYPE_PNG
        );

        $imageinfo = getimagesize($file_array['tmp_name']);
        $width = @$imageinfo[0];
        $height = @$imageinfo[1];
        $type = @$imageinfo[2];
        $mime = @$imageinfo['mime'];

        if (!in_array ($type, $imageTypes)) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        if ($width < $minWidth || $height < $minWidth) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'errorsize';
            die();
        }

        if($mime != 'image/gif' && $mime != 'image/jpeg' && $mime != 'image/png') {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        }

        switch($type) {
            case 1:
                $ext = '.gif';

                //check if is animated gif
                $frame = 0;
                if(($fh = @fopen($file_array['tmp_name'], 'rb')) && $error != 'error') {
                    while(!feof($fh) && $frames < 2) {
                        $chunk = fread($fh, 1024 * 100); //read 100kb at a time
                        $frames += preg_match_all('#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00(\x2C|\x21)#s', $chunk, $matches);
                   }
                }
                fclose($fh);

                break;
            case 2:
                $ext = '.jpg';
                break;
            case 3:
                $ext = '.png';
                break;
        }
        $original_filename = preg_replace('/[^(\x20|\x61-\x7A)]*/', '', strtolower(str_ireplace($ext, '', basename($url)))); //preg_replace('/[^(\x48-\x7A)]*/' strips non-utf character. Ref: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000
        $file_array['name'] = strtolower(substr($original_filename, 0, 100)) . '-' . $filename . $ext;

        $attach_id = media_handle_sideload($file_array, $post_id);

        if (is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
            @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            echo 'error';
            die();
        } else {
            if ($frames > 1) {
                update_post_meta($attach_id, 'a_gif', 'yes');
            }
        }

        update_post_meta($attach_id, 'pinc_unattached', 'yes');

        $return = array();
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id, 'medium');
        $return['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail[0];
        $return['id'] = $attach_id;

        do_action('pinc_after_upload_pin_web', $attach_id);
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried high priority but function pinc_upload_pin_new() is not calling i have put exit in my new function but it is not calling what is issue

Comment: is there any error in console? while ajax call is made?

Comment: not any error in console. and i have print $_files in media_handle_uplod it is printing. if it goes in our new function than media_handle_uplod should not call because i have put exit in our new function so.

Comment: Try,
echo 'testing';die;
this line below the remove_action(....)
inside your new function and see if we are getting in your new function or not.

Comment: Do you have access to the javascript code that makes the ajax call to pinc-upload-pin ??

Comment: i got solution friend. i have created one plugin and define function in that and apply priority and it is worked great thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone if the above answer does not fits you then here is an alterntive method to remove the action hook added by themes.

```
function wpso682524_remove_action()
{
  //Remove the unwanted previous hook added by your theme.
   remove_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin'); 

  //Now hook your new function to that hook.
   add_action('wp_ajax_pinc-upload-pin', 'pinc_upload_pin_new',9);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpso682524_remove_action');
```